# Need better solution to iterate over input lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 5 input lines in my form. i need to retain any blank lines that are between two set of filled but but remove rest of them. For example : 1st line is blank. 2nd line contains text. 3rd line is blank. 4th line contains text and 5th line is blank. i need to retain only 3rd blank line since it's between two filled lines but remove 1st and 5th line. Any easy way of doing that via jquery instead of iterating the input text lines multiple times?

```
<div id="formtextLines">
   <input type="text"> -->blank
    <input type="text"> --> filled line 1
    <input type="text"> --> blank
    <input type="text"> --> filled line 2
    <input type="text"> --> blank
</div>
```

TIA

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - we need to see examples of data and effort and code. Click the `<>` to enter code, jQuery may not be needed here since plain JS can handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not a cutesy jQuery one-liner, but still this only iterates over the inputs one time:

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  var inputs = $("#formtextLines input")
  var defaultLast = inputs.length
  var lastNonBlank = defaultLast
  inputs.each(function(i) {
    if (this.value != "")
      lastNonBlank = i
    else if (lastNonBlank === defaultLast)
      $(this).remove()
  }).slice(lastNonBlank+1).remove()

})
```

```css
input { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Remove blanks</button>
<div id="formtextLines">
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text" value="Non-blank 1">
   <input type="text" value="Non-blank 2">
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text" value="Non-blank 3"> 
   <input type="text"> <!-- blank-->
   <input type="text"> <!-- blank-->
</div>
```

In case it's not obvious, the idea is that as we iterate we remove blank lines immediately if we've not yet found a non-blank line, otherwise we just make a note of the index of the last non-blank line seen so far. Then after iterating, we `.slice()` from the element *after* the last non-blank one and remove those too, noting that `.slice()` will return an empty set if its "start" argument is greater than the index of the last element (so there won't be an error if the whole list is blank or if the last line was not blank).

Note that this doesn't have the problem where removing elements from a list during iteration messes up the indices of following elements, because we're removing the elements from the DOM, not from the list.

EDIT:

> ***"Is there any way instead of removing the empty lines can I just find the indexes of first non blank line and the last non blank line."***

Yes, you can easily adapt what I've already given you to do that - it's easier than what you originally asked for. Already you have the last one in the `lastNonBlank` variable. Just get rid of the `.remove()` and `.slice()` calls and add another variable for `firstNonBlank` with an appropriate test. I'd suggest defaults of `-1` for the case where there are no non-blanks. (Expand/run the following snippet to see this in context.)

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  var firstNonBlank = -1
  var lastNonBlank = -1
  $("#formtextLines input").each(function(i) {
    if (this.value != "") {
      lastNonBlank = i
      if (firstNonBlank === -1)
        firstNonBlank = i
    }
  })
  console.log(firstNonBlank, lastNonBlank)

})
```

```css
input { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Get indices of first and last non-blanks</button>
<div id="formtextLines">
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text" value="Non-blank 1">
   <input type="text" value="Non-blank 2">
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text"> <!--blank-->
   <input type="text" value="Non-blank 3"> 
   <input type="text"> <!-- blank-->
   <input type="text"> <!-- blank-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way instead of removing the empty lines can I just find the indexes of first non blank line and the  last non blank line. in your example firstNonBlankLine will be 2 and lastNonblankLine will be 6 ?

Comment: I've added that to the end of my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for such an in depth explanation. this really helped me!